# Spring data CrudRepository with custom controller methods overrides other endpoint methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a repository that extends `CrudRepository`

```
public interface MerchantRepository extends CrudRepository<Merchant, String>
```

This genrates a POST `/merchants` endpoint which I can use to save and a GET `/merchants` which I can use to query.
Next I implemented a custom save endpoint in the controller because I want to exclude auto-generated fields such as ID from the @RequestBody DTO entity

```
@RestController
public class MerchantController {

    private final MerchantService merchantService;

    @Autowired
    public MerchantController(MerchantService merchantService) {
        this.merchantService = merchantService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping(path ="merchants")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Merchant save(@RequestBody MerchantInputDTO merchantInputDTO) {
        return merchantService.save(merchantInputDTO);
    }
}
```

When I do this, POST `/merchants` works as expected, but other methods on the `/merchants` endpoint, such as GET `/merchants` (used to get all merchants), generated by the `CrudRepository` no longer work and return `405 Method Not Allowed`.

The same thing seems to happen if I implement a custom method on the `/merchants/{id}`. Take for example this custom PATCH on `/merchants/{id}` which then breaks POST `/merchants/{id}`:

```
   @PatchMapping(path ="merchants/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Merchant patch(@RequestBody MerchantInputDTO merchantInputDTO, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return merchantService.patch(merchantInputDTO, id);
    }
```

It seems that by implementing a custom method on an endpoint, it breaks all other methods on that endpoint.

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: It might be possible you have not annotated @ RestController over the class. It seen to be like something missing the MediaType ( e.i @ Produces, @ Consumes). Update the exception message in detail for better and accurate solutions

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but aren't the generated endpoint /merchants and the new "save" endpoint /merchants the same? From your code snippet I would expect the new POST endpoint to override the generated POST request.

Comment: @Jimmy I have the @ RestController annotation, i just omitted it. Please see the edited code chunk. The controller methods I have correctly parse the input and output. The only error I am receiving is the one i have shared.

Comment: @StrongPoint you are right I had a typo, please see the updated question :)

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense to me. :) Try using the RepositoryRestController Annotation instead of RestController. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @StrongPoint in the comments, the solution to this is to use the `@RepositoryRestController` annotation instead of `@RestController`. After making that change I also had to annotate the return type with `@ResponseBody`, leaving the controller looking like this:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class MerchantController {

    private final MerchantService merchantService;

    @Autowired
    public MerchantController(MerchantService merchantService) {
        this.merchantService = merchantService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path ="merchants")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody Merchant save(@RequestBody MerchantInputDTO merchantInputDTO) {
        return merchantService.save(merchantInputDTO);
    }

    @PatchMapping(path ="merchants/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody Merchant patch(@RequestBody MerchantInputDTO merchantInputDTO, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return merchantService.patch(merchantInputDTO, id);
    }
}
```